# Try to get auth token from MobileFirst8.0 to web application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-auth

How can i get auth token by token endpoint /az/v1/token from mfp8? I try to get it by Postman http "post" request with non confidential client credentails and have been getting "errorCode":"invalid_client" all the time. What do i need for validateCredentials method, on my Security Check, works? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As a first step, you need to register a confidential client for your use. Specify the scopes that you need authenticated into. Once this is done, in your Postman REST client, provide the confidential client credentials in Basic authentication, grant type and scopes in the headers.

Fire away and you should have the Bearer token for your use.

More details [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/fr/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/confidential-clients/).

Comment: Thank you. I need different auth tokens for different clients/users.I need some like session objects for these different users too. When any one user, with auth token, will ask protected mfp8 Java adapter, i need to have info wich userlogin it is. Similar i want something that does WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken method, but in free way, whithout mfp8 Client Libraries.

Comment: What you are asking is possible only using client SDK libraries. The token endpoint provides you Bearer tokens covering the scopes requested. To be able to differentiate and track different logins, you need the MFP client SDK libraries.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to simulate multiple clients for some test scenario, Please follow this blog https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/09/performance-testing-for-mobilefirst-foundation-8-0/#prerequisites

Using JMeter ,test flow that emulates multiple MobileFirst clients is described in detail with step by step instruction and scripts.